# Android viewpager doesn't work after including facebook SDK

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-facebook

I have an app using a viewpager with some nested fragments.

However when I include the facebook SDK the viewpager functionality suddenly stops working.

I'm using android studio, so here is the build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:+'
}
```

After I've remove the facebook SDK the viewpager starts working again.

For reference, this is how I've setup my viewpager:

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_music_tab_manager, container, false);
    ViewPager vpPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.vpPager);
    adapterViewPager = new MusicPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    vpPager.setAdapter(adapterViewPager);

    FragmentTabHost mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabHost); //Id of tab host

    setupViewPager(vpPager, mTabHost); //Sets up the on page change listener.
    setupTabs(mTabHost, vpPager); //Sets up the tabs.

    return rootView;
}
```

Setup view pager just set up an on page change listener.

```
    public void setupViewPager(ViewPager vpPager, final FragmentTabHost mTabHost) {

    vpPager.setOnPageChangeListener(
            new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    // When swiping between pages, select the
                    // corresponding tab.
                    //getSupportActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                    mTabHost.setCurrentTab(position);
                }
            });
}
```

And this is the Adapter I am using:

```
public class MusicPagerAdapter  extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public MusicPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int i) {

    switch (i) {
        case 0:
            return new SongsFragment();
        case 1:
            return new ArtistsFragment();
        case 2:
            return new AlbumsFragment();
        case 3:
            return new PlaylistsFragment();
        default:
            return new DefaultNavigationObjectFragment(); //Returns a default fragment in case the switch doesn't work out.
    }
}
```